# Difference between adding MySql Parameters with Add() and AddWithValue()

Tags: .net, mysql, mysql-parameter

According to MySql in this document [C.7.9.6. Changes in MySQL Connector/NET 5.0.5 (07 March 2007)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-net-news-5-0-5.html):

> Added `MySqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue` and marked the `Add(name, value)` method as obsolete.

I've been using `.Add` up until recently and experienced no problems. Upon discovering the `.AddWithValue` method, it is preferable primarily because it involves less syntax.

My question: does anyone know if there is any functional difference between the two methods? I cannot find proper documentation on them.

**Edit:**

Microsoft makes this note about SqlParameterCollection:

> `AddWithValue` replaces the
>   `SqlParameterCollection.Add` method that
>   takes a String and an Object. The
>   overload of `Add` that takes a string
>   and an object was deprecated because
>   of possible ambiguity with the
>   `SqlParameterCollection.Add` overload
>   that takes a String and a SqlDbType
>   enumeration value where passing an
>   integer with the string could be
>   interpreted as being either the
>   parameter value or the corresponding
>   SqlDbType value. Use `AddWithValue`
>   whenever you want to add a parameter
>   by specifying its name and value.

Perhaps it is for the same reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the documentation says nothing, consult the source.
These methods are identical (in their implementation):

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a <see cref="MySqlParameter"/> to the <see cref="MySqlParameterCollection"/> given the specified parameter name and value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parameterName">The name of the parameter.</param>
/// <param name="value">The <see cref="MySqlParameter.Value"/> of the <see cref="MySqlParameter"/> to add to the collection.</param>
/// <returns>The newly added <see cref="MySqlParameter"/> object.</returns>
[Obsolete("Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)")]
public MySqlParameter Add(string parameterName, object value)
{
    return Add(new MySqlParameter(parameterName, value));
}

public MySqlParameter AddWithValue(string parameterName, object value)
{
    return Add(new MySqlParameter(parameterName, value));
}
```

http://mysql-connector-net-5.0.sourcearchive.com/documentation/5.0.8.1/parameter__collection_8cs-source.html

Comment: Didn't even think to check the source! Thanks for both the information and the reminder.